# Where is the error in hibernate caused by ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BINARY

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I get an exception by hibernate:

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BINARY
```

What is exactly the error?
I have the error in `tx.commit()` line:

I only do:

```
Horario horario = new Horario();
horario.setId(new HorarioId("correo",10,2));
```

and then

```
tx = session.beginTransaction();
session.save(horario);
tx.commit();
```

and the class Horario is:

```
public class Horario implements java.io.Serializable {

    private HorarioId id;
    private Datos datos;
    private Serializable entrada;
    private Serializable salida;

    public Horario() {
    }
```

HorarioId is

```
public class HorarioId implements java.io.Serializable {

    private String email;
    private int semana;
    private int dia;

    public HorarioId() {
    }
```

thanks in advance

I supposed that the hbm file is the next:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 14/12/2015 05:47:47 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="hbm.Horario" table="HORARIO">
        <composite-id name="id" class="hbm.HorarioId">
            <key-property name="email" type="string">
                <column name="EMAIL" length="20" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="semana" type="int">
                <column name="SEMANA" precision="5" scale="0" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="dia" type="int">
                <column name="DIA" precision="5" scale="0" />
            </key-property>
        </composite-id>
        <many-to-one name="datos" class="hbm.Datos" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
            <column name="EMAIL" length="20" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="entrada" type="serializable">
            <column name="ENTRADA" />
        </property>
        <property name="salida" type="serializable">
            <column name="SALIDA" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

the relation of tables is:

[image]

and the columns of table Horario are:

[image]

Comment: I uploaded the hbm file. The table 'Horario' have relation with table 'Datos'

Comment: In the code snippet you've provided, I can see that you're not setting `Datos`' object in `Horario`'s object. So I think the problem is with your composite primary key. To confirm this, do one thing. Delete `Datos` entry from `Horario` class & mapping file. Also remove all other variables' entry from `Horario`. Keep only the composite PK and try executing the statement.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your serializable property declarations for *salida* and *entrada*. In the table these are timestamps, but you've declared to hibernate that they are serializable which will make it write the object in a binary type.  These should be changed to a timestamp or date type.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html#types-value-basic